# What is the maximum number of decimal places that can be stored in an asset?

Tags: tokens, asset

When creating new `eosio::asset` objects, what is the maximum precision that can be stored in the asset?

Answer (score 1):

In nodeos, `eosio::chain::symbol` only accepts decimals under 18 digits, but `eosio::symbol` in CDT doesn't check its precision. Of course, during [de]serialization, the inner value of symbol is managed by `eosio::chain::symbol`, so error occurs, but if you instantiate `symbol` or `asset` in contract, it can have more that 18 digits. I think `eosio::symbol::is_valid` needs to check maximum decimal digits to keep consistency with nodeos-side symbol struct. (I sent PR about this issue)

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/pull/553

Comment: Can you link the PR please?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 I added the link in answer.